# how can i add password to redis in helm template

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm

I have described helm template for redis"

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Values.rds.service.name }}"
  namespace: {{ .Values.environment.namespace }}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "{{ .Values.rds.service.name }}"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "{{ .Values.rds.service.name }}"
        component_type: "{{ .Values.component_type.name }}"
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: "{{ .Values.rds.docker.hub }}{{ .Values.rds.docker.image }}"
          name: "{{ .Values.rds.service.name }}"
          env:
            - name: REDIS_PASSWORD
              value: "9dtjger"
          ports:
            - containerPort: {{ toYaml .Values.rds.service.port | indent 5 }}
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "{{ .Values.rds.resources.requests.memory }}"
              cpu: "{{ .Values.rds.resources.requests.cpu }}"
            limits:
              memory: "{{ .Values.rds.resources.limits.memory }}"
              cpu: "{{ .Values.rds.resources.limits.cpu }}"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Values.rds.service.name }}"
  namespace: "{{ .Values.environment.namespace }}"
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "3600"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: '*'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-additional-resource-tags: Department=sre,Team=engage-devops,Environment=ev-lab
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: {{ .Values.rds.service.name }}.{{ .Values.environment.namespace }}.lab.engage.ringcentral.com
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: {{ toYaml .Values.rds.service.port | indent 5 }}
  selector:
    app: "{{ .Values.rds.service.name }}"
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Then I deployed it via kubectl apply:

```yaml
kubectl -n mybanespace describe pod rds-5b6996bf-m6pbr 
Name:           rds-5b6996bf-m6pbr
Namespace:      okta-cc-6
Priority:       0
Node:           ip-10-8-29-49.eu-central-1.compute.internal/10.8.29.49
Start Time:     Mon, 03 Aug 2020 21:55:09 +0300
Labels:         app=rds
                component_type=evt
                pod-template-hash=5b6996bf
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:         Running
IP:             10.8.29.39
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/rds-5b6996bf
Containers:
  rds:
    Container ID:   docker://3be73237324f8ba8c0a38420fceffcee65eb386e93afd8efa309212527761c74
    Image:          redis:6.0.6
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://redis@sha256:d86d6739fab2eaf590cfa51eccf1e9779677bd2502894579bcf3f80cb37b18d4
    Port:           6379/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 03 Aug 2020 21:55:14 +0300
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     40m
      memory:  100Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     2m
      memory:  10Mi
    Environment:
      REDIS_PASSWORD:  9dtjger
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-78c7b (ro)
```

When I try to connect to redis with the password I get error `'Warning: AUTH failed'` if I connect without password - `connection successful`. I don't know why the password doesn't work when I use :

```yaml
env:
   - name: REDIS_PASSWORD
     value: "9dtjger"
```

In docker-compose locally I cannot connect without a password.

How can I set a password for Redis in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't specify how you installed Redis❓ (Which Helm Chart). Essentially adding the `--requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}"` and `--masterauth ${REDIS_PASSWORD}"` should do .

If for example, you used the Bitnami Helm chart, you can use the [`usePassword`](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis#parameters) parameter. Then in the template, it gets used [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/redis/templates/redis-master-statefulset.yaml#L106).

✌️

Comment: yes i use Bitnami, and usePassword is default true.